# Contains with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have class "Estimation", this class has a property "EstimationItems" (the type  is IList)

```
public class EstimationItem 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual int Quantity { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Product 
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I have an instance of "Estimation", I'd like to know if "EstimationItems" contain a product with the code "MyCode".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using this :

```
List<EstimationItem> items = new List<EstimationItem>();
// Add items

int searchedCode = 1

if(items.Any(i => i.Product.Code == searchedCode))
{
    // Contained
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Any()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx):

```
bool hasMyCode = yourEstimation.EstimationItems.Any(
    item => item.Product.Code == "MyCode");
```

Answer (score 1):

[Enumerable.Any Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

```
Boolean result = estimationItems.Any(x => x.Product.Code == "MyCode");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from ei in EstimationItems where ei.Product.Code == "MyCode" select ei;
```